# Parse.com push notifications coming delayed or only after Android app restart

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

When testing parse.com push notifications (sent from CloudCode on afterSave), there is something weird.

Sometimes the Android app gets the notification immediately (below 1 second), but other times, it comes after a multi-second delay.
Restarting the app seems to cause the not-yet-received notifications to appear immediately.

What could be the cause?
Could this be a bug in, for example, the parse.com service?

Is there any limit of how many notifications can be sent or received (per unit of time) ?

The problem happens both with custom BroadcastReceiver and with the default system bar notification.

Server-side javascript CloudCode:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Timer", function(request) {
  // from https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code
  console.log("Before Parse.Push.send -- without alert");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

  // http://blog.parse.com/announcements/pushing-from-the-javascript-sdk-and-cloud-code/ :
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
       //alert: "afterSave on a Timer -- Parse.Push.send"
    }
  });

  console.log("After Parse.Push.send -- without alert");
});
```

Custom broadcast receiver in Kotlin (but the problem happens also without the custom BroadcastReceiver) :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super<BaseActivity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    // ...

    registerReceiver()
}

private fun registerReceiver() {
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
    intentFilter.addAction("com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE")

    registerReceiver(MyBroadcastReceiver(), intentFilter)
}

inner class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "MyBroadcastReceiver 2: onReceive: "
                + context + ";" + intent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        loadTimers()
    }

}
```

We are using a non-paid parse.com account for now. Could that affect the timeliness of the reaction to the push notifications?

Edit: if you think, that using push notifications to trigger near-realtime item updates/sync, is not a good idea (either in general or in parse.com), that would also be a valuable answer, especially if an alternative is proposed...

Comment: I get the same problem only when I test the push on Xiaomi phone.

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee of immediate delivery of push notifications.

Comment: @nasch If you could back it with some sort of article, for example, you could make it into an answer here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At karolvrn's suggestion, here's my answer:

I don't think there's any guarantee of immediate delivery of push notifications.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

> You have two options for assigning delivery priority to downstream
>   messages: normal and high priority. Delivery of high and normal
>   priority messages works like this:
>
> - **High priority.** GCM **attempts** to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the GCM service to wake a sleeping device when
>     possible and open a network connection to your app server...
> - **Normal priority.** This is the default priority for message delivery...

I emphasized "attempts", which implies that it does not guarantee that the message will be delivered immediately.

Here's another developer's experience with reliability issues with GCM:

https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/